# How Can I set a Sun real Position through Blender Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to set a sun real position in Blender as following:

```
sun = bpy.context.scene.sun_pos_properties.usage_mode
sun.context.scene.sun_pos_properties.sky_texture
```

How Can I do That ?

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, could you expand a bit your question ? Are you using the Real Sun addon (or whatever it's called ?) when you say position, do you mean the lattitude and longitude ? Time of year ? Hour of the day ?

Comment: Well, I mean, I created a "Sky texture" Nishita. Besides, I want to add this sky to a "sun Real position". How do I do that?